# How do I replay the credits mini game?

Tags: super-mario-bros-wonder

Is there a way to replay the credits minigame in Super Mario Bros Wonder? I want to aim for a new high score, but I'd like to avoid replaying the final stage for every attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way to access the credits minigame again appears to be replaying the final stage and defeating the boss. You will need to replay the stage for every attempt.